# Pass API returning array data from Parent component to Child Component in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

In here i am trying to pass `this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;` bookingInfo array values to my child component.This is my parent component.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
  lineChart = ['line_chart1', 'line_chart2', 'line_chart3', 'line_chart4', 'line_chart5'];
  value = ['33.5M', '67.9M', '90.9M', '09.9M'];
  names = ['cancellations', 'Bookings', 'Modifications', 'Revenue' ];
  bookingInfo = [];

  ngOnInit() {

     this.getBookingInfo();
    }

  getBookingInfo() {
          const params = [];
          params.push({code: 'dateType', name: 'BOOKING'});
          params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
          params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-12-31'});

          this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).subscribe(
            bookings => {
              this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;
              console.log(this.bookingInfo);
          });
      }

}
```

This is my dashboard.component.html

```
<app-summary-chips [lineChart]="lineChart[0]" [value] = "value[0]" [name] = "names[0]" [data] = "bookingInfo"></app-summary-chips>
```

This my child component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary-chips',
  templateUrl: './summary-chips.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary-chips.component.scss']
})
export class SummaryChipsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('lineChart') lineChart: string;
  @Input('value') value: string;
  @Input('name') name: string;
  @Input() data: [];

  ngOnInit() {

   console.log('line chart: ', this.lineChart);
    console.log(this.data);
  }

}
```

This is my summary-chips.component.html

```
<div class="l-content-wrapper c-summary-chip oh" >
  <div class="c-summary-chip__value">{{value}}</div>
  <div class="c-summary-chip__txt">{{name}}</div>
  <!--<i class="a-naked-label a-naked-label&#45;&#45;danger-down fa c-summary-chip__naked-lable"><span class="a-naked-label__span">100.00%</span></i>-->

  <div id= "{{lineChart}}" class="c-summary-chip__graph ">
  </div>
</div>
```

But when i `console.log(this.data);` in child component it prints an empty array.

Comment: You mean console.log(this.lineChart); ? data is anyways empty

Comment: console.log(this.lineChart); this is coming.But i want to take console.log(this.data); to my child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not where setting the data or assigning the value to data. If you want to set data to the variable you need to initialize or set the data that is being passed from the parent component

EDIT

You are trying to pass asynchronous data to child component. You have different solutions to do that. For exemple, you can use ngOnChanges instead of ngOnInit:

```
ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.data);
}
```

Another solution is to use *ngIf, in order to delay the initialization of posts components:

```
<app-summary-chips *ngIf="bookingInfo" [lineChart]="lineChart[0]" [value] = "value[0]" [name] = "names[0]" [data] = "bookingInfo"></app-summary-chips>
```

Comment: Inside getBookingInfo() function i am getting  this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;

Comment: Sorry that part was hidden initially

Answer (score 1):

as your service handler is taking time to fetch data, this.bookingInfo gets updated after some time so initially you wont get any value in child component.

To make it happen try to implement changeDetectionStrategy, please check the below links for better understanding

https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

after implementing this ,when `this.bookingsInfo` is updated then`ngOnChanges()` of child component will be called containing the previous and the current(new) value of `this.bookingsInfo` instead of `onInit()`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting empty list in your child component because the list is updating inside a subscription, this approach is not triggered the angular child component to detect the property changes.

One very quick solution to your problem is that you can pass the observable itself to child component and in the child, you subscribe to the value changes.

#### in your dashboard component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
  lineChart = ['line_chart1', 'line_chart2', 'line_chart3', 'line_chart4', 'line_chart5'];
  value = ['33.5M', '67.9M', '90.9M', '09.9M'];
  names = ['cancellations', 'Bookings', 'Modifications', 'Revenue' ];
  bookingInfoObservalbe;

  ngOnInit() {

     this.getBookingInfo();
    }

  getBookingInfo() {
          const params = [];
          params.push({code: 'dateType', name: 'BOOKING'});
          params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
          params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-12-31'});

          this.bookingInfoObservalbe = this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params)
      }

}
```

#### in your dashboard template

```
<app-summary-chips [lineChart]="lineChart[0]" [value] = "value[0]" [name] = "names[0]" [data] = "bookingInfoObservalbe"></app-summary-chips>
```

#### in your child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary-chips',
  templateUrl: './summary-chips.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary-chips.component.scss']
})
export class SummaryChipsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('lineChart') lineChart: string;
  @Input('value') value: string;
  @Input('name') name: string;
  @Input() data: [];
  bookingInfo = [];

  ngOnInit() {

   console.log('line chart: ', this.lineChart);
   this.data.subscribe(
            bookings => {
              this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;
              console.log(this.bookingInfo);
          });
  }

}
```

> you can find the working sample of this on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmsbua?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts), Hope this will be helpful.